# Assigning value for member variables while creating instance in java

Tags: java

While going through one of the library, I found the following construct in java which is really new for me. Assume there is a class `Point` in `java`.

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    public Point() {}
    public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    }
}
```

While creating instance for `Point`, they initialize the variables `x` and `y` in the instance creation itself as below :

```
Point inst = new Point() {
            {
                this.x = 10;
                this.y = 20;
            }
        };
```

Is this related to `instance block` in java or something different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example:

1. creates an *anonymous* class derived from Point
2. uses an initializer block to intialise values

The syntax:

```
new Object() { ... }
```

looks like an `Object`, but is in fact creating a new object derived from `Object`. The inner braces then declare the initialiser block.

It's a practise occassionally used to initialise collections e.g.

```
new ArrayList<String>(){{
   add("1");
   add("2");
}};
```

etc. One thing to note is that it's an inner class and consequently there's an implict reference to the outer (surrounding) class. Not normally a problem unless (say) you come to serialise this.

Comment: 3. requires the variables to be directly accessible, 4. is generally an abuse of anonymous inner classes. :)

Comment: I'm torn on the abuse bit, I confess. I do believe with great power comes great responsibility however, and document it if I ever use this

Comment: One point to note on the "implicit reference" part - it could create a problem with respect to garbage collection, and one which is tricky to spot, too.

Comment: Yes. If you bin the containing class but hold the inner. It's something I use *sparingly* - most often in unit tests in which you want to create a populated list concisely and in code. Outside that use-case, I can't think when I've ever used it

Comment: I tend to use the Guava collections for such a purpose, but yes - I'm happier to do this in unit tests than production code.